# Porque minha Taxonomy no Wordpress não funciona em nível hierárquico?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomia

Meu problema é o seguinte, registro um custom post type e uma custom taxonomy para o mesmo, ambos com hierarquia habilitada. Registro as 'categorias' do custom type dentro da taxonomy, seguindo o estilo

- Pai

  - Filho
  - Filho Dois

Porém quando salvo um custom type post dentro de uma das duas categorias filho, acontece o seguinte:

[image: Fica desta forma.]

Ou seja, o custom type post é registrado dentro da taxonomy selecionada, mas ela deixa de seguir o nível hierárquico.

Segue abaixo o código de criação do custom type post e da taxonomy.

```
     $label = array(
        'name' => _x('Arquivos', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Arquivo', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Adicionar Arquivo', 'event'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar novo Arquivo'),
        'edit_item' => __('Editar Arquivo'),
        'new_item' => __('Novo Arquivo'),
        'view_item' => __('Ver Arquivo'),
        'search_items' => __('Procurar Arquivo'),
        'not_found' => __('Arquivo não encontrado'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Arquivo não encontrado na lixeira')
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $label,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-upload',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies' => Array('categorias_arquivos')
    );

    register_post_type('arquivos', $args);

    register_taxonomy('categorias_arquivos', array('arquivos'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Categorias',
        'singular_label' => 'Categoria',
        'rewrite' => false)
    );

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('categorias_arquivos', 'arquivos');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um "problema" antigo, mas [considerado como comportamento esperado](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19527#comment:2), como diz um *core contributor* <sup>*</sup>:

> <sup>* (Core Trac ticket - Bug (inválido) - em inglês)</sup>
> *O comportamento é estranho, mas corresponde ao modo como as categorias aparecem depois de salvar um post. Todas as categorias selecionadas são mostradas no topo da lista de categorias, independentemente de sua hierarquia.*

Um outro contruibuidor do código fonte do WordPress criou um plugin para eliminar essa "funcionalidade":

> #### [Category Checklist Tree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-checklist-tree/)
>
> *On the post editing screen, after saving a post, you will notice that the checked categories are displayed on top, breaking the category hierarchy. This plugin removes that "feature".*
> *Additionally, it automatically scrolls to the first checked category. Works with custom taxonomies too.*

O plugin é [bem simples e o código básico](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/category-checklist-tree/tags/1.3.2/category-checklist-tree.php) é:

```
// Função anônima, requer PHP 5.3+
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', function ( $args ) {
    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    return $args;
});
```

A parte em jQuery no plugin é para fazer o scroll da lista até a primeira categoria marcada.